# Is it NAD+ or NAD- or neutral NAD ?

Tags: biochemistry

In glycolysis why NAD is positivly charged , why it's not neutral or negative ?[image]

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: Question can include **why** is it NAD + and not NAD- or just NAD.

Comment: @AliceD I can't see any way to express my opinion about this other than to comment here. This is clearly a question about biochemistry as tagged. I disagree with your decision to put it on hold because you think that it is a better fit at Chemistry. It's really not about chemistry at all, it's about a convention in representing a *biological* coenzyme which appears to conflict with the underlying chemistry. A chemist would have nothing to say about this unless they were a biochemist. QED

Comment: @AlanBoyd perhaps you're right. But then, it shows no research effort whatsoever (**homework**) and the way it is framed makes it unclear exactly what the *why* in the question refers to (structural chemistry versus functional relevance of charge for enzymatic reactions), hence the question is **unclear** as well. I chose the Chemistry close-vote, but as is often the case when I mod-close stuff, it's lacking quality on various fronts. If you can clarify the question it might be re-opened. For what it's worth, I upvoted your answer, but w/o edits this question should be on hold imo.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in thinking that because of the presence of the diphosphate linkage between the two nucleotides in NAD⁺, both of which will carry a negative charge at physiological pH, together with the positive charge on the nicotinamide N, it would be more chemically correct to write NAD⁻. However I think the idea of using NAD⁺ is to emphasise the N atom in the nicotinamide moiety, which is the 'active site' of the coenzyme.

As it says at the [NAD⁺ Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide?wprov=sfti1):

> Although NAD⁺ is written with a superscript plus sign because of the formal charge on a particular nitrogen atom, at physiological pH for the most part it is actually a singly charged anion (charge of minus 1), while NADH is a doubly charged anion.